# What is the proper way to load a custom HTML element with React and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to load some LaTeX on my website, and I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, looking for some advice as I am fairly new to Typescript.

---

main.tsx

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Latex path="/latex/latex.tex"/>
      <TextBox></TextBox>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

---

index.html

```js
    <script type="module">
        import { LaTeXJSComponent } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/latex.js/dist/latex.mjs"
        customElements.define("latex-js", LaTeXJSComponent)
      </script>    
      <style>
        latex-js {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 55%;
          border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
          margin-right: 2em;
        }
      </style>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
```

---

App.tsx:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import TextareaAutosize from '@mui/base/TextareaAutosize';
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send'
import { Alert } from '@mui/material';

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
      interface IntrinsicElements {
        'latex-js': any;
      }
    }
}

export function Latex({ path }: { path: string }) {    
    const [fileContent, setFileContent] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchFile() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(path);
          const text = await response.text();
          setFileContent(text);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching file:', error);
        }
      }
  
      fetchFile();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <center>
        <div>
            <latex-js>{fileContent}</latex-js>
        </div>
        </center>
    );
}
```

---

The way I am currently doing it is to import the script in html, create a custom html element named "latex-js" then in the App.tsx file load the LaTeX data from a file and inject it as a tag. Since I am new to the whole web development thing I was wondering if anyone knows of a better way to approach this kind of thing.

Comment: Why not use a library like https://github.com/zzish/react-latex? Is your website not react based? You might not need react unless you want to complicate a bunch of stuff

Comment: I tried using it, but it didn't load and render full page .tex files as nicely and accurately as latex.js did. While the code here functions, it feels kind of hacky. Also when running lighthouse in google chrome it shows 2k DOM elements. I had an idea of changing the documents to svg or png and just loading them, maybe that is a better method. Performance shows about 86, which isn't terrible I guess.

Comment: If this is a one off thing for a blog, it would be better to export the stuff you want. It looks like react doesn't have a good latex rendering library, but if latex.js suits you, it would be better to use that. There are online APIs that will render and return it. This code looks painful

Comment: Thank you I just found out about MathJax, going to try that to make an SVG.